# Why do I get this error when setting up Android support for Game Maker?

Tags: android, game-maker

Game Maker asks me to install the Android SDK API 13 for it to work. I opened the SDK Manager and clicked at API 13 but I wasn't able to click the "install packages" button.

I clicked at the obsolete and then I was able to install. But when I pressed "Accept Licence" I wasn't able to click install as an error came out:

```
Package Google Tv Addon, Android API 13, revision 1 (Obsolete) depends on Missing SDK Platform Android, API 13".
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

API level 13 isn't the only one you are supposed to install in order to export APKs from Game Maker (Studio, I guess). All you need to do is check [this guide](http://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/216753498-GameMaker-Studio-Android-SDK-and-NDK-setup-) out and follow the steps. I did so and Android module worked fine.